# How to create nested Json array from associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I’m setting up a file browser and want to parse JSON array to get folder hierarchy, but not able to make the structure I want in JSON array from the associative array.

This is the two associative array which I am fetched from the database.

```
$directory  = Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [dir_name] => Car [dir_id] => car ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [dir_name] => Bus [dir_id] => bus ) )

$subdirectory = Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [sub_name] => Toyota [sub_id] => toyota [dir_id] => car) [1] => stdClass Object ( [sub_name] => Volvo [sub_id] => volvo [dir_id] => bus) )
```

I am tried like this

```
$parentdirectory = [];
$parentfolder = [];
$subf = [];
$subfolder = [];

foreach ($directory  as $dir) {
  $parentdirectory['id'] = $dir->id;
  $parentdirectory['value'] = $dir->name;
  foreach (subdirectory as $sub) {
    if ($dir->dir_id == $sub->dir_id) {
      $subfolder['id'] = $sub->sub_id;
      $subfolder['value'] = $sub->sub_name;
      array_push($subf, $subfolder);
      array_push($parentdirectory, $subf);
    }
  }
  array_push($parentfolder, $parentdirectory);
}

echo json_encode($parentfolder);
```

Actually, I want JSON array like this

```
[
    {
        id: "car",
        value: "Car",
        data: [{
            id: "toyota",
            value: "Toyota"
        }]
    },
    {
        id: "bus",
        value: "Bus",
        data: [{
            id: "volvo",
            value: "Volvo"
        }]
    }
]
```

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a201e8c0c80842fb6846f44c2a3b92939ddeb004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreach loop inside foreach loop is inefficient. First create the data array by looping through $subdirectory and then loop through the $directory to get the actual format.

```
$dataArray = array();
$parentfolder = array();

foreach( $subdirectory as $sub ) {
    $dirName = $sub->dir_id;
    if( !isset( $dataArray[$dirName] ) ) {
        $dataArray[$dirName] = array();
    }
    $dataArray[$dirName][] = array('id' => $sub->sub_id, 'value' => $sub->sub_name);
}

foreach ($directory  as $dir ) {
    $dirName = $dir->dir_id;
    if( isset ( $dataArray[$dirName] ) ) {
        $data = $dataArray[$dirName];
    } else {
        $data = array();
    }
    $parentfolder[] = array('id' => $dir->dir_id, 'value' => $dir->dir_name, 'data' => $data);
}

echo json_encode($parentfolder);
```

Comment: Thanks, working fine. how i will add one more child like array                
$childdirectory = Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [child_name] => ABC1 [child_id] => abc1 [sub_id] => toyota [dir_id] => car) [1] => stdClass Object ( [child_name] => ABC2 [child_id] =>abc2 [sub_id] => volvo [dir_id] => bus) )

Comment: You will need to loop through this $childdirectory array like the same way you are looping through $subdirectory array.

Comment: when am adding one more value in directory folder without adding any child, not getting correctly   eg:  
 $directory  = Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [dir_name] => Car [dir_id] => car ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [dir_name] => Bus [dir_id] => bus ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [dir_name] => Truck [dir_id] => truck))

Comment: Updated the answer to handle above case.

Comment: like this only getting, adding parent without any child it's not showing the  parent value. The new parent added 'Truck' not showing in result       [
    {
        id: "car",
        value: "Car",
        data: [{
            id: "toyota",
            value: "Toyota"
        }]
    },
    {
        id: "bus",
        value: "Bus",
        data: [{
            id: "volvo",
            value: "Volvo"
        }]
    }
]

Comment: Thank you so much , working fine. I am new to this, sorry to disturb you again. I added one more child array can you please check this : (https://3v4l.org/YG0ac)

Comment: Not really sure what you trying to do. Perhaps you could ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set `data` as an `array` first, like this:

```
$parentfolder= array();
    foreach ($directory  as $dir) {
        $row_array = array();
        $row_array["id"] = $dir[id];
        $row_array["data"] = array();
            foreach (subdirectory as $sub) {
                if ($dir["id"] == $sub["dir_id"]) {
                    $row_array["data"][] = array(
                        //and so on..
                    );
                }
            }
        array_push($parentfolder, $row_array);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i tried like this. I am getting this way : [
    {
        id: "car",
        value: "Car",
        data: [{
            car: "toyota",
            Car: "Toyota"
        }]
    },
    {
        id: "bus",
        value: "Bus",
        data: [{
            bus: "volvo",
            Bus: "Volvo"
        }]
    }
]

Comment: Inside second foreach am done like this: foreach ($subdirectory as $sub) {
                if ($dir->id == $sub->dir_id) {
                    $row_array['data'][] = array(
                    $row_array['id'] => $sub->sub_id,
                    $row_array['value'] => $sub->sub_name
                    );
                }
            }